# how to stop video player after it has played a video in android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to play a video from a website in an android app. I got the video to play but there are two things I'm concerned about:

1. When I rotate the phone while the video is playing, it reloads the video and starts from the beginning again.
2. After the video has ended it seems like it is still doing something and I can't hit the back button and return to previous activity.

**Java file:**

```
public class IntroVideo extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.intro_video);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    try {

        String link = "http://northeastvision.org/vids/tube_rush.mp4";
        final VideoView video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoDisplay);
        final ProgressDialog mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading video Please wait...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();


        video.setMediaController(new MediaController(IntroVideo.this));
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(link);
        video.setVideoURI(uri);

        video.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

                video.start();
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
            });

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error Connecting!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    }
```

**Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoDisplay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do (that would do both things for you: wrapping up and returning to the previous screen) would be:

```
video.setOnCompletionListener (new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

            mp.release();
            this.finish();//kills current Activity
        }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

1) to prevent reloads when rotate the phone add the property android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize into your Manifest.xml

```
 <activity android:name="IntroVideo"
                android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
```

2) to release resources associated with the MediaPlayer and finish the activity.

```
 video.setOnCompletionListener (new OnCompletionListener() { 
        @Override 
         public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) { 
         video.release() 
         this.finish(); 
          } 
    });
```

Read more about:

[android:configChanges](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config)
and
[MediaPLayer.release():](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#release%28%29)